# Shader compilation error

Tags: c++, opengl

This is the begin of my vertex shader code:

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTextCoord;

layout(location = 0) out float Fog_Val;
```

When compiling a project in Visual Studio 2019, it gives the following error:

error(#106) Version number not supported by GL2

How to remove the error and compile the project? Could this be due to outdated drivers for my video card?

Updated.

I use

```
glewInit();
```

to initializing OpenGL. My video card is ATI Radeon HD 4650. Before I used ATI Radeon HD 5470 and all works fine. I readed in Wiki video cards AMD/ATi Radeon HD 5000/6000/7000/8000 supports OpenGL 4.4. May be my videocard is outdated. Is there solution?

Comment: How are you initializing your OpenGL device in your code?

Comment: Updated question, glewInit();

Comment: That's how you initialize the OpenGL Extension Wrapper, which is a separate step. Instead of showing one line at a time, try to include in your question a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. That is, the tiniest OpenGL program you can write that can run on its own, attempt to compile that shader, and throw the error. Once folks can reproduce the error you're seeing, they can test potential fixes on that program to be sure they'll work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates you are trying to use OpenGL 4.3 but your graphics card doesnt support it.

From the web

> The Radeon HD 4650 cards come with OpenGL 2.0 support, allowing them to handle graphics rendering efficiently.

Since you are trying to use OpenGL 4.3, this wont work.

The most simple solution is to use a lower OpenGL version, or get a better graphics card, the HD 4650 is almost 20 years old. A used graphics card can be pretty cheap if your looking for a budget option, my GTX 1050 Ti isnt the best of the best, but it was £60 and goes up to OpenGL 4.6.

Comment: I switched to #version 330 and now works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped, make sure to mark it as an answer if it solved your problem :)